# Why this expression throws an error?? eval("{'x': gridSize, 'y':gridSize}")?

Tags: syntax-error, eval

i was messing around with eval, but stumbled across this error:

VM153:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
at :2:1

the code is:

var gridSize = 20;
eval("{'x': gridSize,  'y':gridSize}")

what is happening here???

I was expecting the vm to compile it, since if you remove the quotation marks around the expression it works

Comment: `{x: gridSize}` is a block with a labeled statement.

Comment: so, it's not an object with two properties? how do I turn it into an object with the x and y properties set to 20??

Comment: You could use parentheses around the curly brackets.

Comment: @FelipeRamosMendes What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Progman The error he quoted seems to be a V8 one, so it's probably JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval()` takes a statement sequence. So something like `eval('{x: 10}')` will be syntatically correct, but does not do anything. It is a block consisting of a labeled statement.

If you do `eval("({'x': 10})")`, that will return an object with a `x` property.

It's not common to use `eval` though! Also, interestingly, `eval` returns the value of the last expression statement...